Error when trying to add "DwmSetWindowAttribute" in a basic window
I tried merging two code snippets from Microsoft and unfortunately, for this one, I looked at a lot of different solutions and tried quite a few but could not find out what is wrong and how to correct it.
I am using VS 2022 Community Edition, and it is set to C++14. I started with a basic "Windows Desktop Application" taken from the Microsoft Website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=msvc-170). It is using quite a few Win32 commands but I am ok since I am able to find good references online. Before I added a few line of codes, I ran the program and it worked as expected, that is, displaying a window with a message. I then added some code, again, taken directly from the Microsoft Website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/composition-ovw). I added the needed

#include <dwmapi.h>

at the top of the source code. Since DisableNCRendering is a function, I added a call to it right after the CreateWindowEx command. Eventually, my goal is to play around with DwmWindowAttribute.
Now, when I run the code, I get an error message, unresolved external symbol _imp_DwmSetWindowAttribute...:

What I understand is that there is a call somewhere that is unknown because it cannot find the link to it. I tried different things but without any success. One option I found was to use a [dllimport] statement but I am unsure where to put it in the code. Anyway, here is the complete code. I have highlighted with comments the three places were I have added code.
// HelloWindowsDesktop.cpp 
// compile with: /D_UNICODE /DUNICODE /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /c

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
//******************************************************************************** 
//**************************** THIS PART WAS ADDED *******************************
#include <dwmapi.h> 
//******************************************************************************** 
//********************************************************************************


// Global variables

// The main window class name. 
static TCHAR szWindowClass [ ] = _T ( "DesktopApp" );

// The string that appears in the application's title bar. static
TCHAR szTitle [ ] = _T ( "Windows Desktop Guided Tour Application" );

// Stored instance handle for use in Win32 API calls such as
FindResource HINSTANCE hInst;

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc ( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );


//******************************************************************************** 
//**************************** THIS PART WAS ADDED ******************************* 
HRESULT DisableNCRendering ( HWND hWnd ) {
     HRESULT hr = S_OK;

     DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY ncrp = DWMNCRP_DISABLED;

     // Disable non-client area rendering on the window.
     hr = ::DwmSetWindowAttribute ( hWnd,
          DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY,
          &ncrp,
          sizeof ( ncrp ) );

     if ( SUCCEEDED ( hr ) )
     {
          // ...
     }

     return hr; } 
//******************************************************************************** 
//********************************************************************************


int WINAPI WinMain (
     _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
     _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
     _In_ int       nCmdShow ) {
     WNDCLASSEX wcex;

     wcex.cbSize = sizeof ( WNDCLASSEX );
     wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
     wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
     wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
     wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
     wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
     wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon ( wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION );
     wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor ( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
     wcex.hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH ) ( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
     wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
     wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
     wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon ( wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION );

     if ( !RegisterClassEx ( &wcex ) )
     {
          MessageBox ( NULL,
               _T ( "Call to RegisterClassEx failed!" ),
               _T ( "Windows Desktop Guided Tour" ),
               NULL );

          return 1;
     }

     // Store instance handle in our global variable
     hInst = hInstance;

     // The parameters to CreateWindowEx explained:
     // WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW : An optional extended window style.
     // szWindowClass: the name of the application
     // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
     // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
     // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
     // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
     // NULL: the parent of this window
     // NULL: this application does not have a menu bar
     // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
     // NULL: not used in this application
     HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx (
          WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
          szWindowClass,
          szTitle,
          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
          CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
          500, 100,
          NULL,
          NULL,
          hInstance,
          NULL
     );

     if ( !hWnd )
     {
          MessageBox ( NULL,
               _T ( "Call to CreateWindow failed!" ),
               _T ( "Windows Desktop Guided Tour" ),
               NULL );

          return 1;
     }


     //********************************************************************************
     //**************************** THIS PART WAS ADDED *******************************
     HRESULT test = DisableNCRendering ( hWnd );
     //********************************************************************************
     //********************************************************************************


     // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
     // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
     // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
     ShowWindow ( hWnd,
          nCmdShow );
     UpdateWindow ( hWnd );

     // Main message loop:
     MSG msg;
     while ( GetMessage ( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) )
     {
          TranslateMessage ( &msg );
          DispatchMessage ( &msg );
     }

     return ( int ) msg.wParam; }

//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) 
// 
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window. 
// 
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window > 
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return 
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc ( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {
     PAINTSTRUCT ps;
     HDC hdc;
     TCHAR greeting [ ] = _T ( "Hello, Windows desktop!" );

     switch ( message )
     {
          case WM_PAINT:
               hdc = BeginPaint ( hWnd, &ps );

               // Here your application is laid out.
               // For this introduction, we just print out "Hello, Windows desktop!"
               // in the top left corner.
               TextOut ( hdc,
                    5, 5,
                    greeting, _tcslen ( greeting ) );
               // End application-specific layout section.

               EndPaint ( hWnd, &ps );
               break;
          case WM_DESTROY:
               PostQuitMessage ( 0 );
               break;
          default:
               return DefWindowProc ( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
               break;
     }


     return 0; }

Thanks again for taking the time to read my post and thank you for any insight you can provide.

Look at the Requirements section.  Did you specify Dwmapi.lib as one of the import libraries to link to?  All a header file does is make the compilation happy and produce object code.  When it comes time to actually take the object code and put together the executable, the linker takes over and sees if the functions you are calling actually exist somewhere.  This last step is the one you are missing.

your headline is about merging text. the error and problem that you have is about linking. could you please edit your question? for example i had to read through all post to figure out the issue. question kinda needs a question mark somewhere.

@PaulMcKenzie your url link points to a reference of some function. did you mean link to microsoft linking process?

Tactical note:  I try to avoid the TCHAR stuff and explicitly use the ANSI or Wide versions exclusively. This prevents surprises. The whole TCHAR rigamarole was a neat solution for the problem of Microsoft having two OS lines back around the turn of the millennium using different characters and needed a simple way for folks to write code for both lines. This hasn't been an issue since Windows XP crushed all in-house competition back in the early 2000s. These days it's usually best to just go all-in on wide characters because that's what the surviving OS line prefers.

@user14063792468 -- The link points to the function that the OP is referencing.  Down in that page is the Requirements section, and more than likely the OP did not meet the "library" requirements.  My additional comment on linking is that a lot of new C++ programmers do not understand the process of how a C++ application is built, i.e. compilation and linking.

@PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the suggestion. I looked at it and I downloaded the new SDK and it is installing now. Will see if I am able to resolve it.

I think all you needed was to set the Linker settings in your project and add Dwmapi.lib.

@PaulMcKenzie that is what OP needed. he speaks specifically about linking step.

@user4581301: I understand what you are saying about Wide. Once I get into building a more "final" version, I will update that. For now, I am just trying to get the pieces working on their own.

Side note: Rather than taking a screenshot of the Error List, click over to the Output tab usually found nearby. The Output tab provides the complete build diagnostic in plain text you can paste into Stack Overflow. Plus often the information that was edited out to show a pretty summary of problems in the Error List and is still visible in the Output tab is all you need to understand and resolve the error. Because the output tab is more useful, I don't think I've looked at the Error List in decades. That said, I don't use Visual Studio that much.

As suggested by @user4581301, here is the error message within the Output tab:
SmallestWin32WindowFile.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol imp_DwmSetWindowAttribute referenced in function "long cdecl DisableNCRendering(struct HWND *)" (?DisableNCRendering@@YAJPEAUHWND@@@Z)
1>C:

@PaulMcKenzie: Just to make sure, is this where you suggested I put dwapi.lib? Sorry, I tried to include a picture,but I can't. So in the Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories.

@RHILLE Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.  The Additional Library Directories just tells the linker where to find the libraries.  You still need to tell the linker which libraries to link, and that is where the Additional Dependencies comes into play.  There are also other ways to specify the libraries to link to within the source code using #pragma comment(lib:library_name), but try and get it to work the "traditional" way first.

@PaulMcKenzie: Perfect! It works. I also tried it with the "non-traditional" way and it also works. Thank you so much for your help!

A note about #pragma and why Paul stresses the first option over the second: #pragma are implementation-specific compiler tricks. Some, like #pragma once, have wide compiler support, but they are not universal. Worse, a compiler that doesn't support a #pragma is allowed to silently ignore the directive, though most compilers now issue a compiler warning.
